# generate classification accuracy matrix from results dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, classification

I am trying to predict a binary classification.  I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains two columns: one is predicted membership in the class, the other is actual membership in the class.  From this DataFrame I want to create another DataFrame that represents my prediction accuracy.  I'm looking for a clean way to do this that doesn't involve concatenating strings or anything like that.

Desired result DataFrame:

```
    True_Actual False_Actual
True_Pred   6         1
False_Pred  1         2
```

Sample input DataFrame:

```
    MAHC_ACTUAL MAHC_PREDICT
1   True         True
2   True         True
3   False        True
4   True         True
5   True         True
6   True         False
7   False        False
8   True         True
9   False        False
10  True         True
```

Comment: Cool. Good luck doing that! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straight forward way to do this is use `pandas.crosstab` which gives you *a frequency table of the factors*:

```
pd.crosstab(df.MAHC_PREDICT.astype(str) + "_Pred", df.MAHC_ACTUAL.astype(str) + "_Actual")
```

[image]

For simplicity, if column and index names aren't important:

```
pd.crosstab(df.MAHC_PREDICT, df.MAHC_ACTUAL)
```

Yeilds:

```
MAHC_ACTUAL  False  True 
MAHC_PREDICT                    
False           126      2
True             13    113
```